# Which is correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

Which is correct:

> I may have catch a cold.

Or

> I may have caught a cold.

Should I use *"may"* or *"might"* and *"catch"* or *"caught"*?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you done to solve this problem (apart from the obvious thing - posting it here :D)? I am sure there are many posts here about *may* vs *might*.

Comment: Have you learnt to conjugate the English verb _to catch?_  ( @Man_From_India The problem is the verb form of _to catch,_ not the conditional!)

Answer (score 2):

If you use **have** before a verb, you are probably trying to make a perfect: in this case it's an infinitive form of the [present perfect](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/present-tense/present-perfect). A perfect requires a past participle: for catch, the past participle is **caught**. The correct version is therefore

> I may have caught a cold.

In this context, there is little difference between **may** and **might**: they both introduce the idea of a low probability.

Comment: Technically, it's a *perfect*, unqualified: the 'tense' is on *may/might*, and the *have* is an infinitive. And I'd say the modality introduced here involves 'uncertainty' rather than 'probability'.